# Сортировка массива в JS (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, сортировка

Получаю данные с сервера.

```
 _.forIn(response.favorites, function(tournamentObj, key) {
         var sortedItem = {};
         sortedItem._id = tournamentObj._id;
         sortedItem.group = tournamentObj.groupAlias;
         sortedItem.tournament = tournamentObj;

         FavoriteLocalService.pushInFavoriteList(sortedItem);
});
```

Потробнее:

o функции [*_.forIn*](https://lodash.com/docs#forIn),
**response** - обьект с сервера,
**FavoriteLocalService.pushInFavoriteList()** - функция которая добавляет обьект в массив сервиса.

Надо сортировать массив так чтоб *sortedItem.group* по занчению **'default'** былы первыми.

```
array = [
  {
    sortedItem._id = 1;
    sortedItem.group = 'default';
    sortedItem.tournament = {};
  },
  {
    sortedItem._id = 2;
    sortedItem.group = 'default';
    sortedItem.tournament = {};
  },
  {
    sortedItem._id = 3;
    sortedItem.group = 'otherGroup';
    sortedItem.tournament = {};
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по описанию, вы используете [lodash](https://lodash.com). С помощью него можно отсортировать массив методом [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy):

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(array, 'group', 'default');
```

где `array` - сам массив, `'group'` - путь ключа объекта, `default` - значение по пути ключа. Массив будет отсортирован по возрастанию, элементы с одинаковым совпадением сохранят порядок.

---

Если использовать AngularJS, то можно воспользоваться фильтром [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

```
app.service('TestService', function($filter) {

    var array = [...];

    var sorted = $filter('orderBy')(array, 'group!=="default"');

});
```

Как и в случае с lodash вариантом, порядок элементов подпадающих под условие сохранится.

Answer (score 2):

У массивов есть метод `sort`, который параметром принимает функцию, сравнивающую два элемента. Функция должна возвращать значения 1 или -1 (в зависимости от того, какой элемент должен быть больше), и 0 в случае равенства двух элементов.

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.group == b.group) return 0;
    if(a.group == 'default') return 1;
    if(b.group == 'default') return -1;

    return 0; //в независимости от других свойств считаем что объекты равны
});
```

Note: это нативный JS, angular тут не при чём.